# Batch commands to search directory

Tags: batch-file, directory, copy

I'm trying to search a directory for the latest file (specified by filename) and then copy that latest file to another directory.

The following code had worked before but I'm not exactly sure why its breaking now.

```
:COPY
forfiles -p\\ServerLocation\Search\This\folder\location\ -mMyFileName.txt -c"robocopy @PATH \\ServerLocation\Copy\File\here @FILE /XO /log:\\ServerLocation\Create\LogFile\Here\My_Log.log" -s
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks